# How to change/customize the response format of Lighthouse?

Tags: laravel, graphql, response, laravel-lighthouse

I am using Lighthouse GraphQL with Laravel 9 for my application. Graphql have standard format and each response show under the data and operation name. It does not show proper response (error/success) to handle for front-end application. Because, on the basis of error code iOS/Android/frontend may work easily. Here is the sample:
**Request:**

```
query Translations {
        translations {
            name
            slug
        }
    }
```

**Response:**

```
{
        "data": {
            "translations": [
                {
                    "name": "English",
                    "slug": "en_US"
                },
                {
                    "name": "English (United Kingdom)",
                    "slug": "en_UK"
                }      
            ]
        }
    }
```

I have tried to override response with Laravel response classes and create custom queries/mutations resolver. But, it returns all the information. This should use Graphql "Tailoring your need" also. So, I want to customize the response so that response should include code, status, message, data[].

**The result I got:**

```
{
        "status": true,
        "code": 200,
        "message": "",
        "data": [
            {
                "_id": "63b2d767e2a07754b20845f6",
                "name": "English",
                "slug": "en_US",
                "isActive": true,
                "isDefault": true,
                "updated_at": "2023-01-02T13:08:54.940000Z",
                "created_at": "2023-01-02T13:08:54.940000Z",
                "logo": "/United-States.svg"
            },
            {
                "_id": "63b3e78ae2a07754b20845ff",
                "name": "English (United Kingdom)",
                "slug": "en_UK",
                "isActive": true,
                "isDefault": false,
                "updated_at": "2023-01-03T08:30:02.085000Z",
                "created_at": "2023-01-03T08:30:02.085000Z",
                "logo": "/Great-Britain.svg"
            } 
        ]
    }
```

**It should be:**

```
{
        "status": true,
        "code": 200,
        "message": "",
        "data": [
            {     
                "name": "English",
                "slug": "en_US"      
            },
            {      
                "name": "English (United Kingdom)",
                "slug": "en_UK"      
            }    
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Show us how you are executing those queries, show what you have done so far.

Comment: @KGG I have created a Translations custom resolver within that 
namespace App\GraphQL\Queries;
use App\Models\Translation;
use App\GraphQL\BaseClass;

final class Translations extends BaseClass
{
    public function __invoke($_, array $args)
    {
        $translations = Translation::all();
        $this->sendResponse($translations, '', $this->HttpCode::$SUCCESS);               
    }
}
The sendResponse method is defined under BaseClass. The sendResponse method have response format is defined to overwrite dynamically

Answer (score 2):

> It should be:

```
{
        "status": true,
        "code": 200,
        "message": "",
        "data": [
            {     
                "name": "English",
                "slug": "en_US"      
            },
            {      
                "name": "English (United Kingdom)",
                "slug": "en_UK"      
            }    
        ]
    }
```

I would strongly advise against this, as it violates the [GraphQL specification](https://spec.graphql.org/October2021/#sec-Response-Format):

> To ensure future changes to the protocol do not break existing services and clients, the top level response map must not contain any entries other than the three described above.

Use `extensions` for custom additions. You can add to extensions in Lighthouse by listening to the `BuildExtensionsResponse` event, see https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/events.html#buildextensionsresponse

Answer (score 1):

Lighthouse returns the response based on the [GraphQL specification](https://spec.graphql.org/October2021/#sec-Response-Format). You have the power to change the response with the [EndRequest](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/events.html#endrequest) event. Listen to the event in `AppServiceProvider` and then manipulate the response in any form that you need.

```
/**
 * @param Dispatcher $dispatcher
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot(Dispatcher $dispatcher): void {
    $dispatcher->listen(
        EndRequest::class,
        function (EndRequest $endRequest) {
            dd($endRequest->response);
        });
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks @mostafa!! It works for me what exactly I want. I need more clarity I can override the response  but unable to remove the method/operation name.
{
  "status": true,
  "code": 200,
  "message ": "",
  "data": {
    "translations": [
      {
        "slug": "en_US",
        "name": "English"
      },
      {
        "slug": "en_UK",
        "name": "English (United Kingdom)"
      }
    ]
  }
I want to remove "translations" key and all response should come under data only.
How can I track errors as well?

Comment: It is a JSON, convert it to an array and do whatever u want then convert it back to JSON.

Comment: Yes. I know and I did the same but I'm unable to send the customized value in the response. It gives original response.
        $dispatcher->listen(
            EndRequest::class,
            function (EndRequest $endRequest) {
                $data = json_decode($endRequest->response->getContent());
                $dataArr = array_values((array)$data->data);
                $responseData['status']= true;
                $responseData['code'] = 200;
                $responseData['data'] = $dataArr[0];
                return json_encode($responseData);                
            });

Comment: Please check the current code. Am I doing wrong. According to Request lifecycle where should response go.

Comment: $endRequest->response->setContent(json_encode($responseData));